# Ember js Disconnect Outlet doesnt clear cached template data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, outlet

i have a modal where i open and via a outlet 
so opened it using following code

```
this.render( controller, {
  into: 'application',
  outlet: 'modal'
} );
```

then in the modal view i have a computed property

```
  peopleArray: computed ('someDataFromaMixin' , function (){
    debugger;
    return this.get( 'someDataFromaMixin' )
  }),
```

then i close the modal using below code

```
removeOutlet: function( ) {

    return this.disconnectOutlet( {

      outlet: 'modal',
      parentView: 'application'
    } );
  },
```

issue is the computed property compute if i go there with a page refresh

if i close the modal and re-open again the computedProperty will not trigger ( even if i modified the computed property data )

im clueless what cause this issue

Comment: what do you mean by *modal view*? And how do you * modifiy the computed property data*?

Comment: computed properties cache their values and only recompute upon dependent key changes. setting the same value twice will not recompute the property on the second set. observing an object doesn't recompute when one of it's properties changes unless you explicitly reference the property `computed('someDataFromaMixin.prop'`. It would be helpful if you could provide more clarity in your question, either by demonstrating the setting with code, or better with an ember twiddle

Comment: @Lux im changing the value of the peopleArray when there is a click on the listed items ( setting peopleArrays-> person.selected = true ) . 
im using modal ( bootstrap modal ) . as outlets

Comment: @sunrize920 thank you for the reply. my question is why disconnectOutlet doesnt remove the template cached data? i have similar code in ember 1.13 as well and it works

Comment: *How* do you change the data in the peopleArray? by setting someDataFromaMixin? How do you set it? And agin *where* is this computed property? And whats the ember version? And to answer "why disconnectOutlet doesnt remove the template cached data": why would it?

Comment: peoplearray is populated in to a list in hbs
  {{#each peopleArray as |result|}}
{{othercompoenent data=result action=changeToSelected }}
 {{/each}}

Comment: This does not answer my questions. Can you maybe provide a non-working example with ember-twiddle or a git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this issue by triggering model's rollBackAttributes method when i fired the action to close the modal view. so then i can preserve the original state of the model which is modified in the modal view where it is rendered through an outlet